# Spring Data Neo4j - labels not stored correctly with inheritance

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have class hierarchy like this with corresponding repositories:

```
@NodeEntity
@TypeAlias("BASE")
public class Base {

@NodeEntity
@TypeAlias("Child1")
public class Child1 extends Base {

@NodeEntity
@TypeAlias("Child2")
public class Child2 extends Base {
```

When

1. I save an instance of Child1,
2. retrieve it as Child2 using either Child2Repository.findOne or Neo4jTemplate.findOne methods
3. save it using Child2Repository

then it will correctly store properties of Child2 class but it won't store the labels for Child2 class. Then I can't find the node using the Child2Repository.findAll method.

I have following test case

```
    Child1 child1 = child1Repository.save(new Child1("child1", "prop1"));

    Child2 child2 = neo4jTemplate.findOne(child1.getId(), Child2.class);

    child2.setProp2("prop2");
    child2Repository.save(child2);

    Node node = neo4jTemplate.getNode(child1.getId());

    logger.info("Labels: {}", node.getLabels());
    for (String key : node.getPropertyKeys()) {
        logger.info("Property: {}, value: {}", key, node.getProperty(key));
    }

    assertThat(baseRepository.findAll().as(List.class).size(), is(1));
    assertThat(child1Repository.findAll().as(List.class).size(), is(1));
    assertThat(child2Repository.findAll().as(List.class).size(), is(1));
```

which outputs

```
Labels: [BASE, Child1, _Child1]
Property: prop2, value: prop2
Property: prop1, value: prop1
Property: name, value: child2
```

and fails on last line. **Is this desired behaviour or a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?**

Sample project on github:

https://github.com/frant-hartm/neo4j-examples/

Answer (score 0):

You saved a node with a *prop1* attribute, then you fetched it, added a *prop2* attribute to it and saved it, therefore the final result is a node with two attributes *prop1* and *prop2*.

Comment: Yes, this works as expected, what is missing are labels Child2 and _Child2 on the node.

Comment: The node was created as a Child1 and after is saved as a Child2, it seems reasonable that the class is only assigned the first time it's created. Anyway IMHO it's not a good practice changing the type of a node once it has been stored in the database.

Comment: The use case is quite common, imagine a TeamMember (Base) and Developer(Child1) becoming also ProjectManager(Child2).

Comment: In that case I would delete the node and create a new one